# How to know which button clicked using this.Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using .net 1.1 In My page,i have few `ImageButtonClientSide` Controls and some other buttons which causes `postback.Now` I want to know,when page postbacks,In `Page_Load` which control has been clicked?I am currently doing like this

```
  if ( Check.IsNotNulOrBlank(this.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]) ) 
 {
            if(this.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Equals("imgButtonSearch"))

            {

                                  }
  }
```

But `this.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` is showing empty values.

Comment: See the full `Request.Form` to find out what is send. My guess is that you need to look for the `imgButtonSearch.UniqueID` and if is inside the form then you do have a post back from that button.

Answer (score 0):

There is different way to check that for postback done byButton and image button 
Please look at this article link given below. 
It clearly tells how to achieve that for image button

[How to know which control has triggered the Post back event.](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-know-which-control-has-triggered-the-Post-back-event-417.php)